# Using float value in Google Line chart using PHP

Tags: php, json, charts

Line chart is drawn very fine using (int) values using Google Charts API (see exact below code) but one of the percentage column value is in float so I tried (floatval) instead of (int) but PHP server file throws 500 internal server error.

What is the solution in especially at to use float value?

```
(int)str_replace("%", "", $row['percentage'])
```

Also note that, my values are coming as JSON from MySQL.

PHP (server file):

```
   $rows[] = array(explode(" - ", $row['started_on'])[0].trim(), 'Coverage');
        while($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $rows[] = array(explode(" - ", $row['started_on'])[0].trim(), (int)str_replace("%", "", $row['percentage']));
        }
```

JS (in php):

```
// Draw line chart
function drawLineChart(chartType, chartTitle) {
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(lineChartData);

    function lineChartData() {
        var lineChartJsonData = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "<?php echo $general_scripts; ?>",
            data: { id1: chartType, id2: "Chart", id100: "<?php echo $getPage; ?>" },
            dataType:"json",
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#progress").show();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#progress").hide();
            },
        }).responseText;

        var options = {
            title: chartTitle,
            width: '390',
            height: '300',
            backgroundColor: '#f5fffa',
        };

        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(($.parseJSON(lineChartJsonData)));
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(chartType));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(float) works fine, here it is:

```
$rows[] = array(explode(" - ", $row['started_on'])[0].trim(), (float)str_replace("%", "", $row['data']));

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Give this data to chart.draw(data, options);